# Tabula-py font error tahoma when parsing pdf

Tags: python, pdf, debian, tabula

I'm running on debian jessie. I'm trying to parse my pdf with [tabula-py library](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) but I get this error

```
   2016 12:16:57 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont 

getawtFont  
0                                             Italic                          
1   2016 12:16:57 PM org.apache.fontbox.util.Font...                          
2                                             Italic                          
                                       Oct 13  \
0  INFO: Can't find the specified font Tahoma   
1                                      Oct 13   
2             WARNING: Font not found: Tahoma
```

How can do to fix that ?

Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from wand.image import Image
from tabula import read_pdf_table

# Converting first page into JPG
with Image(filename="ed.pdf", resolution=200) as pdf:
    pdf.compression_quality = 99
    pdf.save(filename="temp.png")

img = cv2.imread('temp.png', 0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv2.imread('test cust.png', 0)
imgw, imgh = img.shape[::-1]
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR', 'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc

    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

    top = top_left[1];
    left = top_left[0];
    bottom = imgh - bottom_right[1];
    right = imgw - bottom_right[0];

    cv2.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, [0,255,0], 10)

    df = read_pdf_table('ed.pdf', area=(top,left,bottom,right))
    print(df)
```

The error will be happened at this line

`df = read_pdf_table('ed.pdf', area=(top,left,bottom,right))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm author of tabula-py. I guess you would like to extract image based PDF, but tabula-py isn't a tool for OCR. It is assumed to extract text embedded PDF.

I think you should try OCR tools such as [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/).